# Left Join vs. Inner Join causing different results when using Substring/Left functions

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring

Would anyone be able to explain why the following query returns a result set:

```
SELECT sub.*, xr.*
FROM (
    select  rc.CommentID,
            [CreateDate] = LEFT(rc.Comments, 10),
            [CreatedBy] = SUBSTRING(rc.Comments, 12, CHARINDEX(':', rc.Comments) - 12),
            src.Comments
    from dbo.RequestComments rc
    where rc.CommentID NOT IN( 4290, 4289, 4221)
) sub
LEFT JOIN dbo.SWDBCWUserXRef xr
 ON sub.CreatedBy = xr.EnteredByName
```

...but, if I modify it to use an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT sub.*, xr.*
FROM (
    select  rc.CommentID,
            [CreateDate] = LEFT(rc.Comments, 10),
            [CreatedBy] = SUBSTRING(rc.Comments, 12, CHARINDEX(':', rc.Comments) - 12),
            src.Comments
    from dbo.RequestComments rc
    where rc.CommentID NOT IN( 4290, 4289, 4221)
) sub
JOIN dbo.SWDBCWUserXRef xr
 ON sub.CreatedBy = xr.EnteredByName
```

I receive the following error:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Likely because you're getting more records in the INNER JOIN where the SUBSTRING...CHARINDEX(... is producing a negative value.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that you do, if this is the entire query.   Why did you tag `common-table-expression` when you are not using one?   Can you post a script that reproduces the problem?  Most likely explanation:  the problem is occurring in some part of the code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Most likely the compiler is processing the join first without considering the NOT IN, resulting in some CreatedBy being NULL / -1, etc.  Maybe consider a CTE (may do the same), or a temptable/table variable for subquery.

Comment: @mjw how could changing from a LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN result in more records?   And how can the type of JOIN in the outer query affect the LEFT() or SUBSTRING() which is in a single-table subquery?

Comment: Replace your SUBSTRING expression with anything...say, 'TEST' and see if you still get the same error. Guessing you have some data you're not expecting in the rc.Comments column.

Comment: I deleted my answer since i couldn't determine the issue with it. I would still like to know @zackP is the column 'src.comments' in your select is that a typo or are you missing some additional tables from your example? you dont have a table with that alias referenced.

Comment: Compare query plans (CTRL-L). As already mentioned, you'll probably find that things are being done in a different order, meaning more records are processed by substring, including ones that break your expression 0 i.e. comments that don't contain ':'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sub.*, xr.*
FROM (
select  rc.CommentID,
[CreateDate] = LEFT(rc.Comments, 10),
[CreatedBy] = SUBSTRING(rc.Comments, 12, CHARINDEX(':', rc.Comments) - 12),
src.Comments
from dbo.RequestComments rc
where rc.CommentID NOT IN( 4290, 4289, 4221)
) sub
JOIN dbo.SWDBCWUserXRef xr
 ON SUBSTRING(rc.Comments, 12, CHARINDEX(':', rc.Comments) =    xr.EnteredByName
```